# rvalue reference and polymorphism

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, rvalue-reference, object-lifetime, temporary-objects

When I run the following code I get the following runtime crash:

"pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception"

I dont understand why polymorphism doesn't work here. Please can someone help me.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void print()=0;
    virtual ~Base(){}
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
    void print(){cout << "this is Derived\n";}
};

struct Foo
{
    Foo(Base&& r): bref{r} {}
    void print(){
        bref.print();
    }
    Base& bref;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f{Derived()};
    f.print(); //it crashes here with above message
}
```

Comment: `Derived()` creates a *temporary* object. An object that is destructed once the call to the `Foo` constructor is finished. Where do you think the reference `bref` is actually referencing once the temporary object is destructed?

Comment: You shouldn't assign an r-value reference to an ordinary one. Either use two ordinary references or assign the r-value reference to an object instance; if you want to profit from move semantics, you should do: `{ Foo(Base&& r) : bref(std::move(r)) { } Base bref; }`

Comment: @Aconcagua since `Base` is pure virtual it will not compile.

Comment: @MarekR Then make it a `Derived` instance; anyway what's the point of the rvalue ref here? You don't want to "steal" an instance, avoid a copy, etc.

Comment: @curiousguy I'm not OP just pointing out wrong comment.

Comment: @MarekR Yes; but even with a concrete class Base, it would probably be a logic error to convert a Derived to a Base

Comment: @MarekR Was intended to present options *in general*, considered `Base` not being instantiable a different topic (seems as if I wasn't clear enough about...). Similarly didn't consider object-slicing issues even if base *was* instantiable...

Comment: All, I understand now the error due to Derived() being a temporary object. I would like to be able to use the following expressions: Foo f1{Derived1()}; Foo f2{Derived2()}; f1.print() ; f2.print(); etc. Do you have any suggestion in this case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lifetime of the temporary object `Derived()` extends until the full expression that is `Foo f{Derived()};`. `f.bref` is a dangling reference after that. `f.print()` calls `bref.print()` which has undefined behaviour.

`Foo{Derived()}.print();` would be technically well defined, but storing an lvalue reference into an rvalue referred object passed to a constructor probably makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

`bref` is a dangling reference when you call it in `Foo::print()`. Maybe use `unique_ptr` like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
struct Base
{
    virtual void print()=0;
    virtual ~Base(){}
};

struct Derived: public Base
{
    void print(){std::cout << "this is Derived\n";}
};

struct Foo
{
    Foo(std::unique_ptr<Base>&& r): bref{std::move(r)} {}
    void print(){
        bref->print();
    }
    std::unique_ptr<Base> bref;
};

int main()
{
    Foo f{std::unique_ptr<Derived>(new Derived)}; //or make_unique
    f.print();
}
```